# Why this class/instance variable is not being intialized?

Tags: object, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I am trying to use gnu-smalltalk. In following code of a simple class with a variable, I find it is not getting initialized to the given value:

```
Object subclass: Myclass[
    |mainval|
    mainval := 555.
    getmainval [^mainval]
]

gc := Myclass new.
gc getmainval printNl.
```

The object gets created without any error. But, the output is:

```
nil
```

while I had expected it to be 555.

If I add a method to assign a value to it and call it after creating an instance of the class, it works.

Where is the problem and how can it be corrected? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were close but you tried a shortcut which does not work due to the fact that you are expecting that setting value to an instance variable within class definition (outside a method and local validity) will return value. In reality you want to use an instance variable within a method e.g. `init` to express the inner state of an object.

As I have noted in some previous answers, I'm not a GNU Smalltalk expert.  I'm using Smalltalk/X-jv branch for programming.

I have taken the liberty to rewrite your code to more GNU Smalltalk like code:

```
Object subclass: MyClass [
    | mainVal |
    <comment:
        'testing main value'>
    MyClass class >> new [
        <category: 'instance creation'>
        | myClass |
        myClass := super new.
        myClass init.
        ^ myClass
    ]
    init [
        <category: 'initialization'>
        mainVal := 555.
    ]
    mainVal [
        ^ mainVal
    ]
]
```

The explanation:

I'm defining the `mainVal` instance variable.  Then I'm redefining a class method `new` which is **not** needed but for illustration purposes I'm doing so. (The `new` message is inherited from `Object` class)

What I'm doing in the class method `new`.  I'm sending the `new` message to the `superclass` which creates instance of `anObject`, then initializing the `myClass` with `init` and then returing it.

Afterwards you can see the `init` class which initialize your instance variable to your wished value of `555`.

Then you have a getter (in Smalltalk it is usual to have it without the *get* prefix, but that is "only" matter of style) the `mainVal`.

Then your code to call the object and get value.

```
gc := MyClass new.
gc mainVal
```

The **minimal example** without the `new` message redefinition:

```
Object subclass: MyClass [
    | mainVal |
    <comment:
        'testing main value'>
    init [
        <category: 'initialization'>
        mainVal := 555.
    ]
    mainVal [
        ^ mainVal
    ]
]
```

What you must not forget that in Smalltalk there is usually no default calling of a constructor so you have to send the `init` message manually (the other option is to redefine `new` message like I did above).

Then using it would look like this:

```
gc := MyClass new.
a MyClass
st> gc init
a MyClass
st> gc mainVal
555
```

Comment: Very well explained.